# In VB.NET why should I use Select, instead of If?

Tags: vb.net, select, if-statement, language-features

I've recently graduated and started a real job. In our training they've been exposing us to VB.NET and a lot of the features they use here. In some of the examples, they've used `Select` statements (and in a few places they were used where an `If/Else` really should have been used).

The only time that I've used a switch/select statement in other languages (other than assignments that required it) has been when I wanted the fall through to the next statement.

Given than VB.NET has no fall through, what (if any) cases are there to use the `Select` statement? Are there any cases when it provides advantages over and `If/ElseIf` statement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Select Case`, not just `Select`.
To me, it's one of the best features of the language.

1. It's much more visual when you have several possible values to test against.

   ```
   select case some_var
   case 1
     something()
   case 2
     something_else()
   case 3
     etc()
   end select
   ```
2. It's much more readable when it comes to testing ranges:

   ```
   select case some_var
   case 1 to 10
     something()
   case 20 to 30
     something_else()
   case is > 100
     etc()
   end select
   ```
3. It's much more readable when you have a bunch of more complex conditions to test, making sure only one is selected:

   ```
   select case true
   case string.isnullorempty(a_string)
     something()
   case a_string.length < 5
     something_else()
   case a_string = b_string
     etc()
   end select
   ```
4. It's superior to C/C++ `switch` in the sense that it allows expressions as branching points, not just constants.
5. When using constants as branching points (example 1), compiler is able to generate a more optimised code with direct jumps.

Comment: I was completely unaware that you could test ranges, and quite a few good arguments for `Select Case`

Answer (score 6):

`Select` tells the compiler that every compare (If) in the analogous set of If/Else blocks is on the same value, and this allows it to make certain optimizations that are harder to be sure of otherwise. For example, it might be more eager to generate machine code that holds that value in a cpu register (that's just hypothetical... different compilers can do what they want).

Also, some of us find `Select` a lot more readable.  It is important to follow the coding standards of whatever team or unit you find yourself.

Answer (score 4):

First off, VB does have fall through, it's just not as obvious. The "fallthrough" in VB is just setting one case to have multiple values:

```
Dim number As Integer = 8
Select Case number
    Case 6,7,8
        ' do stuff
    Case Else
        ' do default stuff
End Select
```

As for its advantages, it's way easier to write one `Select` statement than say, more than three `If/ElseIf` statements that all test against the same value.

Comment: It's not fall through now, is it? Most of the it covers it but it's still not the same functionality.

Comment: @dr. evil - for all intents and purposes it's fallthrough. it's more like a safety net than a fall through. basically, you can't unintentionally create fallthrough like you can in C# by just forgetting to `break;`

Comment: I don't know if I'd consider that true fallthrough, since in say - C++ you can run a few operations on one case - perhaps consume a few things. The best example that I saw was converting to roman numerals from integer, but can't find the link now.

Comment: @wayne that's the point. the reason they made select different in VB was to prevent the dev from accidentally forgetting to break it. in my opinion fallthrough is basically always unintentional or if it's not, 99% of the time you can do something better than abusing fallthrough. in VB, you get to specify your fallthrough if you want it and there's no way to create it unintentionally (unless you screw up your ranges :)

Comment: @wayne that's what I was referring but apparently C# doesn't allow that anyway so effectively Jason is right this is the exact same behaviour with C#'s fallthrough without and VB.NET's syntax is much more elegant.

Comment: If a C or C++ programmer puts two case statements in a row followed by a block of code, ok, they want that code executed for either value. But if he puts a case statement, some code, no break, another case statement, and more code, in my humble opinion the code now becomes cryptic. Is the fall-thru intentional, in the first case both blocks should be executed but in the second case only one?, or did he just forget the break? I suppose you could put in a comment to clarify but usually the programmer doesn't, and the reader is left to wonder. I think it's therefore bad coding style. IMHO the ...

Comment: ... VB syntax of putting multiple values separated by commas is superior. When multiple values should execute the same code, it is clear and readable. If you really have a case where when the value is 1 you want to do X and Y and on 2 you want to do just Y, put them in subroutines and write the proper calls, and your code will be clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to do several different things based on the input comparison/range comparison if it's if-elseif+ then use `Select` instead of crazy if-elseif blocks.

VB.NET's Select statement has some cool features as well, so ensure that you know all the features.

Comment: Using fall through to do crazy switch stuff (I'm not referring to just supporting multiple values which is normal)

Comment: evil: C# doesn't allow case fall-through except for specifying multiple values. If you want to go to another case, you have to manually `goto case` into it.

Comment: Damn! You right, I always assumed it's like C++, my bad, updated the post. I'm quite impressed with C# now that they removed this ridiculous feature :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a situation where Select Case can be much more efficient than If: when you have a list of "Or" clauses in the If condition and you do not need to evaluate them all to establish the truth of the condition. Suppose you had an if statement such as this:

```
If A() Or B() Then
    DoSomething()
ElseIF C() or D() Then
    DoSomethingElse()
Else
    DoTheDefault()
EndIF
```

In this case, to evaluate the first if statement, both functions A() and B() are executed, and similarly for the second if statement when A() and B() are both false. If A() returns true, then the value of B() is immaterial and, unless it changes the program state in a way that you actually want it to (generally not good practice), the execution of B() is redundant. The compiler is constrained by the requirement that all parts of the test MUST be executed before concluding on a value (optimisation of the test is not allowed according to the language spec).

You could separate the conditions into multiple IfElse statements to optimise it yourself but this makes the code less readable and increases the danger of errors when changes are made later. I find that using Select Case is better in this situation:

```
Select Case True
    Case A(), B()
        DoSomething()
    Case C(), D()
        DoSomethingElse()
    Case Else
        DoTheDefault()
End Select
```

Now, if A() returns True then B() is not evaluated at all. The evaluation of the conditions is in the sequence listed, so you can help to optimise your code by putting the tests in the order of most likely to return True or least expensive to execute (depending on the application).

Comment: You can also change `Or` to `OrElse` to achieve the same behavior with `If/Else`. Still, +1 for your efforts on explaining everything clear.