# IEEE754 Half Precision (16 bit) floating point data in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, precision

Does VB.Net support IEEE 754 half precision (16 bit) floating point data types?
If not, is there a recommended way of creating them?

Context: I am ultimately sending a stream of bytes over a COM channel to a device that accepts half precision values. I need to take the `Decimal` value entered by the user and convert it to a two byte float for transmission. I am unsure the best way to do this in VB.Net

Comment: The smallest is `Single` (32bits)

Comment: Would be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10414889/11683 but that question is about fitting a float in two bytes in any way, not just according to IEEE. Still, it references http://sourceforge.net/projects/csharp-half/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not associated at all with this library, but you can use [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/csharp-half/code/HEAD/tree/System.Half/).

It's a struct that uses internally an `ushort` member, which should be what you are transmitting. If you can't transmit the struct directly for some reason, you could just make the `value` field `public`, and use that (or use the `GetBytes()` method).

I'm unsure about the precision of the conversion though, you should experiment.

The library is C#, but there should be no problem adding it as a C# project to your solution and use it from Vb.Net

## Update

I took the time and made a "safe" minimum version in Vb.net. All the code is from that library, all copyrights to him:

```
Public Class HalfPrecisionConverter
    Private Shared BaseTable As UShort() = GenerateBaseTable()
    Private Shared ShiftTable As SByte() = GenerateShiftTable()

    Private Shared Function GenerateBaseTable() As UShort()
        Dim intBaseTable = New UShort(511) {}
        For i = 0 To 255
            Dim e = CSByte(127 - i)
            If e > 24 Then
                ' Very small numbers map to zero
                intBaseTable(i Or &H0) = &H0
                intBaseTable(i Or &H100) = &H8000
            ElseIf e > 14 Then
                ' Small numbers map to denorms
                intBaseTable(i Or &H0) = CUShort(&H400 >> (18 + e))
                intBaseTable(i Or &H100) = CUShort((&H400 >> (18 + e)) Or &H8000)
            ElseIf e >= -15 Then
                ' Normal numbers just lose precision
                intBaseTable(i Or &H0) = CUShort((15 - e) << 10)
                intBaseTable(i Or &H100) = CUShort(((15 - e) << 10) Or &H8000)
            ElseIf e > -128 Then
                ' Large numbers map to Infinity
                intBaseTable(i Or &H0) = &H7c00
                intBaseTable(i Or &H100) = &Hfc00
            Else
                ' Infinity and NaN's stay Infinity and NaN's
                intBaseTable(i Or &H0) = &H7c00
                intBaseTable(i Or &H100) = &Hfc00
            End If
        Next

        Return intBaseTable
    End Function

    Private Shared Function GenerateShiftTable() As SByte()
        Dim intShiftTable = New SByte(511) {}
        For i = 0 To 255
            Dim e = CSByte(127 - i)
            If e > 24 Then
                ' Very small numbers map to zero
                intShiftTable(i Or &H0) = 24
                intShiftTable(i Or &H100) = 24
            ElseIf e > 14 Then
                ' Small numbers map to denorms
                intShiftTable(i Or &H0) = CSByte(e - 1)
                intShiftTable(i Or &H100) = CSByte(e - 1)
            ElseIf e >= -15 Then
                ' Normal numbers just lose precision
                intShiftTable(i Or &H0) = 13
                intShiftTable(i Or &H100) = 13
            ElseIf e > -128 Then
                ' Large numbers map to Infinity
                intShiftTable(i Or &H0) = 24
                intShiftTable(i Or &H100) = 24
            Else
                ' Infinity and NaN's stay Infinity and NaN's
                intShiftTable(i Or &H0) = 13
                intShiftTable(i Or &H100) = 13
            End If
        Next

        Return intShiftTable
    End Function

    Public Shared Function SingleToHalf([single] As Single) As UShort
        Dim value As UInteger = BitConverter.ToUInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes([single]), 0)

        Dim result = CUShort(baseTable((value >> 23) And &H1ff) + ((value And &H7fffff) >> shiftTable(value >> 23)))
        Return result
    End Function
End Class
```

To use:

```
HalfPrecisionConverter.SingleToHalf(xx)
```

It returns a `UShort`, if you need the bytes to transmit, you can use `BitConverter.GetBytes()`

The C# unsafe version should be a bit faster since it does not use `BitConverter` and directly uses pointers to convert the single to a `UInteger` of its bytes, but I'm not sure VB.NET allows for any kind of pointer conversions

Comment: VB does not have pointers, but you can [abuse a union](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6474800/11683). You don't have to though, because you can [send a `ushort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8sh9zw1e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) down a stream just as well. Also I would advise to [use `select case`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6540220/11683).

Comment: @GSerg I'm no vb coder, just made the "safe" version in C# using the original library code (and changed to use `BitConverter` and ran it through an online code converter (and tested it on a project before submitting it here)