# VBA Select Case number to number greater than and less than

Tags: vba

```
Sub ss()
  Dim a As Double
  a = 6.99999999
  Select Case a
    Case 0 To 7:
      MsgBox "ok"
    Case Else:
      MsgBox "no"
  End Select
End Sub
```

The `Case 0 to 7` results in a check for `a >= 0 and a <= 7`. But what I want is `a >= 0 and a < 7`.

I also tried `Case Is >=0, Is < 7`.

How can I do this in a `Select Case`?

- `a = 6.99999999` should result in "ok"
- `a = 7` should result in "no"

Comment: er just `case 0 to 6` ?

Comment: waht about 6.99999?

Comment: "You can use multiple expressions or ranges in each Case clause. For example, the following line is valid. 
`Case 1 To 4, 7 To 9, 11, 13, Is > maxNumber` " [Select...Case Statement (Visual Basic) MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement)

Comment: in that case `Select Case Fix(a)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select case true
  case a >= 0 and a < 7
    MsgBox "ok"
  case else
    MsgBox "no"
end select
```

But, unless you have more than two conditions, I would suggest you use an `If` instead.

Comment: This defeats the purpose of `Select Case` all together. `Select Case True` is just a dummy wrapper here.

Comment: @trincot To me `select case true`is a [more readable alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/794091/11683) to a series of `ElseIf`. I [do not think](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6540327/11683) it defeats anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub ss()
  Dim a
  a = 7
  Select Case a
    Case  7:
      MsgBox "no"
    Case 0 To 7:
      MsgBox "ok"
    Case Else:
      MsgBox "no"
  End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: what about if a = 6.999?

Comment: Then you need to use case 0 to 7, and before that another case 7 with answer "no"

Comment: 6.99999999 should be "ok" and 7 should be "no"

Comment: Yes, that's why if you add case 7: msgBox "no",  and afterwards case 0 to 7: MsgBox "ok"  should be what you are looking for.  Just edited my answer to deal with this situation, as at first I thought we were dealing with integers only. Anyway instead of select  you could use if...

Comment: This works well for small amount of conditions, but will quickly turn into an unmanageable mess if you add more.

Comment: @johnn then you need a better [mcve], because your current use case doesn't justify a `Select Case` structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ss()
  Dim a As Double
  a = 6.99999999
  Select Case a
    Case 0 To 7:
      If a = 7 Then
          MsgBox "no"
      Else    
          MsgBox "ok"
      End If
    Case Else:
      MsgBox "no"
  End Select
End Sub
```

I finally work out this solution. Thank you all!